# How can we customize the dynamic component linking url in SDL Tridion 2013sp1?

Tags: 2013-sp1, link-resolver

I have a custom requirement where all my internal links ending with index.jsp should get resolved without "index.jsp" for example "http://example.com/test/index.jsp" should get resolved to "http://example.com/test/". Currently the internal component link code 

`<a tridion:href="tcm:201-103039">test</a> gets published as 
<tridion:ComponentLink pageURI="tcm:201-104343-64" componentURI="tcm:201-103039" templateURI="tcm:0-0-0" addAnchor="false" linkText="test link" linkAttributes=" title="test page" textOnFail="true"/>` and the page link only gets resolved during page load.
How can we update the page url to remove "index.jsp" from page url ?
Is there a way to resolve the page url during the publishing time ?

Please provide your inputs on this query.

Comment: use URL Rewrite feature in IIS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options here that I can see, and probably a few more that I won't mention.

(1) Application server URL rewrites (such as the [IIS URL rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) Pankaj mentioned). It's pretty powerful and will let you write all sorts of rules for this sort of thing.

(2) Write your own resolver tag. You can read a bit more of the specifics [here](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/cleaning-and-extending-dynamic-linking) (written by Will Price); but essentially you can write your own tag which behaves similarly to the OOTB tag, but with your own added logic. This might be overkill when you can use app-server rewrites, but it's good to know about if additional logic is ever required.

Comment: +1 for the resolver - sounds like the requirement is not to write the index.jsp to the page (possible some SEO or other)

Comment: Thanks Josh for the resolver tag suggestion. This is actually what I was looking for. Using IIS URL rewrite is not an option because of SEO. We are currently using IIS URL rewrite.